# bbb behind pfsense/firewall/nat

Tags: firewall, nat, pfsense

I have a virtualized server with 5 vm, and I have one domain and only 2 public IP (can not buy more IP).

vm1: pfsense, eth1: public IP x.x.x.x, eth2: local IP: 10.0.0.1
vm2, vm3, vm4, vm5 (is empty)
If I can setup at least 3 or 4 bbb vm (behind pfsense, using local eth 10.0.0.x) ?
If I must setup stun/turn server with another my public IP?
If I can NAT ports?
If each bbb server needs one public IP for itself?
Please explain more... Thanks.

Comment: read https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/2.2/configure-firewall

and then put nginx infront and proxy to each

Public -> NAT  -> nginx -> (BBB instances)

Comment: what about:  UDP ports in the range 16384 - 32768 (for FreeSWITCH/HTML5 RTP streams)    Should I FORWARD these ports? How to do it for each BBB?

Comment: you'd have to modify the RTP range of each server ( see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60710416/freeswitch-is-using-different-rtp-ports-than-defined ), basically 32768-16384/(servercount)